# How to reinitialize or render component by click over the same url?

Tags: angular

When I click repeatly over menu link component is not reintialized again, so these dont work:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log('Reinitialize');
}

constructor() {
   console.log('Reinitialize');
}
```

How to reinitialize or render component by click over the same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` is only called one time when the component is very first initilized. However, it still is only a function so you can call it yourself as many time as your want. Though it is worth mentioning that isn't a recommended pattern

In your code you could call say a `reInititialize()` function whenever you click on your menu link:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log('Reinitialize');
}

reInititialize(){
this.ngOnInit()
}
```

Though I would recommend you create perhaps an `initialize()` function and call that in your `ngOnInint()` insteand and then call the  `initialize()` function directly if you  need to rather than continue to call `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize()
    }

    initialize(){
    //Do some operation
    }
```

**P.S.** I may be off base, but I don't have the 50 reputation points it says I need ask questions in comments. I will update if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: May be to use listening of route?